# Python -> transform a number from 0.0002321 to 2321

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to write a code to transform a float number like 0.00123 to 123
I don't really know how to explain it exactly. Let's say I have this code:

```
Entry = float(input("Give me the Entry position: "))
```

we can assume I get the input 0.005686584 I want to delete the initial zeros and get the rest numbers as an output (5686584).

Examples: 0.4537823 -> 4537823,
0.001234 -> 1234

Comment: These examples are not enough. Say I have `00456.78` should it be converted to `45678` ignoring the 0 or it should be `78` (considering the decimal)?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the input as string, remove the 'dot' and convert it to int:

```
entry = input("Give me the Entry position: ") #  0.000023
print(int(entry.replace('.', '')))
```

Out:

```
23
```

Alterntively you could filter out all characters that are not a digit:

```
#  entry = input("Give me the Entry position: ")
entry = "ffff89084023432.092"
print(int(''.join(x for x in entry if x.isdigit())))
```

Out:

```
89084023432092
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `replace()` and want to do some math, check this:

```
n = float(input())
while int(n) != n:
    n *= 10
print(int(n))
```